# jQuery fade in on scroll does not work on mobile

Tags: jquery, iphone, mobile, scroll

I've just found a pretty interesting solution for fading in content on scroll using jquery
http://jsfiddle.net/tcloninger/e5qaD/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
$(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.hideme').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

        }

    }); 

});

});
```

The only problem is that it's not working on iPhone (Safari). How can it be possible to make this solution work on mobile devices?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It may be that this particular method wouldn't be the best solution for mobile. You may want to look up LazyLoading. In mobile, whenever you're fading in a container from below, it signifies that something is loading on demand, when the object comes into view. That way you're not downloading images or other source assets until you need them. I've had great success on client sites with that method.

But going back to your original Q, I'd suggest testing another plugin using the iPhone, in a stripped down environment with no other scripts or content. I hope this helped a little! Good luck man!